# Trigonometric functions help?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

How do I find the equation of this sin function? Would it be y = -1/2 sin (3/2x)-1? Im confused about how to find amplitude and stuff when the problems ARENT on the axis. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer looks good :D  Don't doubt yourself!

Answer (score 2):

This is a function of the type
$$
f(x)=a\sin(bx+c)+d
$$
where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$ are to be found.
First of all the amplitude $a$ is $1/2$ since the wave is between $-3/2$ and $-1/2$, from which you find immediately $d$, in fact the midpoint of $[-1,1]$ is $0$ and the midpoint of $[-3/2,-1/2]$ is $-1$, thus your function is obtained from the original sine by a translation of $-1$ which is thus the value of $d$.

Then you can finally find $b,c$ imposing for example one of the following
$$
f(0)=-1\\
f(\pi/3)=-3/2\\
f(2\pi/3)=-1\\
f(\pi)=-1/2
$$
and exploiting basic properties of the sine function.